# I want to make my async calls more readable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am currently dealing my Promises through calling the async function and then chaining it with .then(). But I would like a more readable approach.

What I currently have that works is

```
const apiCall = async() => {
  const response = await axios.get("URL");
  return response;
}

apiCall().then(res => {
  console.log(res.data);
});
```

What I would like my code to look like:

```
const apiCall = () => {
  const response = axios.get("URL);
  return response;
}

const fetchData = async() => {
  const response = await apiCall();
  return response.data;
}

console.log(fetchData());
```

Comment: Don't mix `async/await` with `.then()` and `.catch()` coding. Use one or the other, preferably `async/await` because it's much cleaner

Comment: Also you cannot make your code look like what you say you want. If `fetchData()` is `async`, it will return a Promise, so using `console.log()` on the result will just show the Promise, not the fetched value.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
const apiCall = async() => {
  const { data } = await axios.get("URL");
  return data;
}
```

Comment: I still get Promise pending, could this be because the program ends so it forces the console log to print the promise before it is resolved?

Comment: Is there any problem with url or api?